# How is $\alpha$ chosen in lasso?

Tags: python, lasso, regularization

I am looking at the scikit_learn (python) implementation of LassoCV.

Below is the function that sets the $\alpha$ values to look at (the penalization coefficient of the L1 norm).

Can anyone shed some light on why it's implemented that way? Specifically:

- why does it take the max of the dot product of X and y as $\alpha_{max}$ ?
- why does it choose eps x $\alpha_{max}$ as the lower bound?

Any help much appreciated.

```
def _alpha_grid(X, y, Xy=None, l1_ratio=1.0, fit_intercept=True,
                eps=1e-3, n_alphas=100, normalize=False, copy_X=True):
    """ Compute the grid of alpha values for elastic net parameter search
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape (n_samples, n_features)
        Training data. Pass directly as Fortran-contiguous data to avoid
        unnecessary memory duplication
    y : ndarray, shape (n_samples,)
        Target values
    Xy : array-like, optional
        Xy = np.dot(X.T, y) that can be precomputed.
    l1_ratio : float
        The elastic net mixing parameter, with ``0 <= l1_ratio <= 1``.
        For ``l1_ratio = 0`` the penalty is an L2 penalty. ``For
        l1_ratio = 1`` it is an L1 penalty.  For ``0 < l1_ratio <
        1``, the penalty is a combination of L1 and L2.
    eps : float, optional
        Length of the path. ``eps=1e-3`` means that
        ``alpha_min / alpha_max = 1e-3``
    n_alphas : int, optional
        Number of alphas along the regularization path
    fit_intercept : boolean, default True
        Whether to fit an intercept or not
    normalize : boolean, optional, default False
        If ``True``, the regressors X will be normalized before regression.
    copy_X : boolean, optional, default True
        If ``True``, X will be copied; else, it may be overwritten.
    """
    n_samples = len(y)

    sparse_center = False
    if Xy is None:
        X_sparse = sparse.isspmatrix(X)
        sparse_center = X_sparse and (fit_intercept or normalize)
        X = check_array(X, 'csc',
                        copy=(copy_X and fit_intercept and not X_sparse))
        if not X_sparse:
            # X can be touched inplace thanks to the above line
            X, y, _, _, _ = center_data(X, y, fit_intercept,
                                        normalize, copy=False)
        Xy = safe_sparse_dot(X.T, y, dense_output=True)

        if sparse_center:
            # Workaround to find alpha_max for sparse matrices.
            # since we should not destroy the sparsity of such matrices.
            _, _, X_mean, _, X_std = sparse_center_data(X, y, fit_intercept,
                                                        normalize)
            mean_dot = X_mean * np.sum(y)

    if Xy.ndim == 1:
        Xy = Xy[:, np.newaxis]

    if sparse_center:
        if fit_intercept:
            Xy -= mean_dot[:, np.newaxis]
        if normalize:
            Xy /= X_std[:, np.newaxis]

    alpha_max = (np.sqrt(np.sum(Xy ** 2, axis=1)).max() /
                 (n_samples * l1_ratio))

    if alpha_max <= np.finfo(float).resolution:
        alphas = np.empty(n_alphas)
        alphas.fill(np.finfo(float).resolution)
        return alphas

    return np.logspace(np.log10(alpha_max * eps), np.log10(alpha_max),
                       num=n_alphas)[::-1]
```

Comment: What is "that way" for those of us who can't see it from the source code? Also how can you tell that $\alpha$ is too high to give a proper answer to your problem?

Comment: Voting to leave open, as I interpret the question to be asking about the purpose behind an implementation, which strikes me as on-topic. Though I suggest answering @transmetro's questions in an edit.

Comment: Is it clearer now? (the question is definitely about the purpose behind the implementation, the math part, not the coding part).

Comment: Can you please either reopen my question or let me know why you feel it's still unclear?

Comment: I believe this question to be within the guidelines of the website. Can someone reopen it, or explain why it's not. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, last call for this. I have edited the question, and I believe this is clearly in line with the site description. Can anyone care to reopen the question, or explain why my edits are insufficient.

Comment: Did you find by now why it works this way?